# Rearranging Content After Blog Post

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

My client has a ton of plugins, and several plugins that automatically puts things at the bottom of their blog posts. I built an author box using Advanced Custom Fields, and it goes below all the other plugins. They use things like “Magic Action Box,” “Facebook Comment Plugin” etc.

How can I get the Advanced Custom Fields to go above these other plugins? I’m a programmer noob, but have the simple PHP author box working.

Comment: How did you add the author box, to the template, or through the `the_content` filter?

Comment: In order to control where something loads, you must dig into the actions and filters that are being used.

Since you haven't included any sample code or screenshots, I am not sure exactly how to direct you. I haven't used the plugin you are asking about (that I am aware of), but you must find out what action or filter it is using to insert your code and then either specify a new action/filter for it to run with, or set the priority on the action/filter to earlier than what it currently is.

Comment: I added the PHP at the very bottom of the single.php file right before the closing loop.You can see the Author Box I created at the bottom of this page: http://www.thesnapsociety.com/business-partnerships/

Answer (score 0):

If editing the theme files, chances are you want to place your custom block of code right after a line of code that might look something like:
`<?php get_template_part( 'content/entry' ); ?>`

It should also be before any call to the function `comments_template()` if you want it to show before the comments.

You mention using a plugin called Facebook Comment Plugin. I don't have any experience with this plugin, but ideally, it would tap into the comments_template function rather than try to filter itself earlier.

Depending on the theme you are using, you may have actions you can tap into that can add your custom block of code. **Using actions is the best option if actions are available.**

In a worst-case scenario, you could use a filter to add your content block to the end of the actual post content:

```
function my_author_box($content) {
    if (!is_feed()) {
        $authorbox = '<p>This is my authorbox code....</p>';
        $content = $content . $authorbox;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_author_box');
```

Again, this previous sample would be added into your `functions.php` file or into a custom plugin, but I would recommend only doing this as a last resort as filtering the_content applies your code in more places than you might expect or want it to.